# automatic js displaying in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i am using login script my using `ajax`,Need to know from where this code could be come as not able to find anywhere in my core files.Able to see below js while checking view source of the site. Platform is `codeigniter`

```
<!-- Begin Attracta Include 2012-10-08 04:51 -->

<script type='text/javascript'> 
function attracta_loadjs(url) {
   (function() {
       var s = document.createElement('script');
       s.type = 'text/javascript';
       s.async = true;
       s.src = url;
       var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
   })();
}
function attracta_shouldrun() {
   var v = ["/admin/","/adm/","/wp-admin/","/administrator/"];
   for (x in v) if(window.location.pathname.indexOf(v[x]) == 0) return false;
   return true;
}
function attracta_window_width() {
   if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) return document.body.offsetWidth;
   if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) return document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
   if (window.innerWidth) return window.innerWidth;
   return 0;
}
function attracta_window_height() {
   if (document.body && document.body.offsetHeight) return document.body.offsetHeight;
   if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetHeight ) return document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
   if (window.innerHeight) return window.innerHeight;
   return 0;
}
</script>

<!-- End Attracta Include 2012-10-08 04:51 -->
```

Answer (score 1):

DELETE a .`fastinclude` file from public_html file and also delete the seo packaging tool in your hosting service and ask your hosting service to disable any `seo` functionality and 
need to cancel attracta via cpanel